# Cryptographic functions as feature map/kernel function?

Tags: discrete-logarithm, one-way-function, lwe, trapdoor, machine-learning

Has there been any use of cryptographic function as a kernel function with support vector machine? There are [several](https://dataaspirant.com/svm-kernels/#t-1608054630727) standard kernels to be used with SVMs each with its own scenario.

I was not able to find any kernel function which is a cryptographic, one-way, or trapdoor function other than [this example](https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.02174) of using discrete logarithm. The context is I would like to find a kernel function which is hard to implement on a classical computer but works nicely as a kernel function if somehow implemented with a black box.

Comment: I only have a restricted knowledge of ML and maybe I didn't understand the purpose of the second paper you mention but what is the purpose of assuming DLP hardness when constructing a quantum algorithm?

Comment: As far as I understood, the DL assumption comes into play only in showing hardness of learning in the classical setting. They then show that since DL assumption does not hold in the quantum setting, there exists a quantum classifier for this class.

Comment: You might get an answer if you state the problem you're trying to solve (rather than some details on a solution you've already picked)

Comment: @JAAAY, my understanding is that the authors wanted to give a contrived example, where a feature map cannot be efficiently implemented using a classical computer.

Comment: @ckamath, yes. I am wondering if there is a general way to create more of such examples.

Comment: @poncho, let's consider a binary classification problem defined over any publicly available dataset. My question is could we use a one-way function as a feature map which improves the generalization error.